# Ubuntu 14.04 fn keys starts to work after resume from sleep

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, suspend, brightness

I have a problem with Ubuntu 14.04. After fresh installation none of the fn keys didn't work except for fn+f3 combination - which is sleep. After resume from sleep all fn keys (brightness, power, wifi) starts to work perfectly until the reboot of the laptop. Any ideas for possible solution? Laptop model is HP nx6310.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a HP 8510w laptop and Ubuntu 14.04 64bit.
The problem is caused by the hp-wmi driver. Block the driver in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and the hotkeys will work immediately after the start of the system